# How to run the command "sfdx force:apex:test:run" so that System.debug statements are printed in the console?

Tags: vs-code

I love the option of running test methods from VSCode by clicking on `Run Test` link that appears below the `@isTest` annotation. This works well but when a test method fails, I go ahead and add a `System.debug()` statement to troubleshoot where it is failing. But it never prints the debug statements from the test method or actual method.

I tried running `sfdx force:apex:test:run --loglevel trace` but still it just prints the result and doesn't print the debug statements.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
sfdx force:apex:log:get
```

to get the last log file or use:

```
sfdx force:apex:log:tail --color
```

to stream the log file output to your console. (See e.g. [Streaming Debug Logs to your console](https://andyinthecloud.com/2018/03/14/streaming-apex-logs-to-your-console/).)

Comment: Ok. I thought we can fiddle with arguments passed to the command `sfdx force:apex:test:run` and get debug statements printed along with pass or fail result. That would have been so handy.

Comment: @javanoob Not AFAIK. But the tail option is pretty nice.

Comment: You are right. This workaround is lot better than going into the developer console for logs.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this!  Here is what we came up with to show only user DEBUG in the stream (similar to the filtered option in IntelliJ/Webstorm with Illuminated Cloud):

```
sfdx force:apex:log:tail --color | grep --line-buffered "USER_DEBUG"
```